# Overload a method in a way that generates a compiler error when called with a temporary

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, rvalue

Perhaps this piece of code will illustrate my intent best:

```
#include <array>

template <size_t N>
void f(std::array<char, N> arr)
{
}

template <size_t N>
void f(std::array<char, N>&& arr)
{
    static_assert(false, "This function may not be called with a temporary.");
}
```

`f()` should compile for lvalues but not for rvalues. This code works with MSVC, but GCC trips on the `static_assert` even though this overload is never called.

So my question is two-fold: how to express my intent properly with modern C++, and why does the compiler evaluate `static_assert` in a "dead" template overload that's never instantiated?

Try it online: https://godbolt.org/z/yJJn7_

Comment: That wouldn't cause a warning but a hard error.

Comment: Do you want `arr` to be modifiable in the function?

Comment: FWIW, prohibiting rvalues doesn't really work. Titus Winters gave [a talk at C++Now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UmDvg5xv1U) and a talk at CppCon (Modern C++ Design) in which he mentioned this. In short, rvalue-ness is not an indicator of lifetime. Disabling an rvalue overload will lead to programmers simply putting the temporary in a local variable, which doesn't really affect the lifetime requirements

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, that's not required. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @Justin: except local variable is perfectly fine in my case, but calling `f` with a temporary will either segfault or produce garbage.

Comment: You are looking for a compilation error when called with a temporary (a pr-value), as written in question title or with a rvalue (as writen in the question body)?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That's true. In most cases, lifetime extension is long enough, but there are cases where prohibiting rvalues does work, such as a scope-guard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to remove the `static_assert` and instead mark the function as deleted.  Then if you call it with an rvalue you will get an error saying you are trying to use a deleted function

```
template <size_t N>
void f(const std::array<char, N>& arr)
{

}

template <size_t N>
void f(const std::array<char, N>&& arr) = delete; // used const here just in case we get a const prvalue

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 3> foo{};
    f(foo);
    //f(std::array<char, 3>{}); // error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `f(X&&) = delete` you should do `f(X const&&) = delete`. The latter will also catch const rvalues - which as-is would prefer your other overload - and works just fine for non-const rvalues.

Comment: @Barry: how would a `const rvalue` look like on the call site? Either I don't understand the concept, or I don't understand how to obtain one.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Same way any other rvalue looks, except it's const. `std::move(x);` is a const rvalue if `x` is const.

Answer (score 3):

Simple enough.

```
template <size_t N>
void f(const std::array<char, N>&& arr) = delete;
```

Comment: @NathanOliver: it does compile on godbolt with MSVC and GCC 8.1.

Comment: Way to go, thank you! I keep forgetting you can `delete` various functions, not just special auto-generated class members.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yeah, it wont compile `f(std::array<char, 3>{});`, which you don't want so that is okay.  It is just that the error message isn't the best: https://godbolt.org/z/VmXY17.  Comment removed

Comment: @NathanOliver compiles for me?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I agree it's not the best, but it will do. Better than a warning you may miss on Windows. Your final solution is better, I guess, but the new meta is to pass by value if possible?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The pass by value is so you have to write less overloads but still get move semantics if passed a temporary.  In this case you don't want temporaries so passing by value isn't needed or really desirable (you'll be making a lot of unneeded copies).

Comment: @NathanOliver: So copy elision _only_ applies to rvalues?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes.  You can't elide an lvalue (well you can but that is for function local variables that are returned)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using only a single function that takes a reference to a non-const object:

```
template<size_t N> void f(std::array<char, N>& arr);
```

No more overloads needed.

This rule *is* enforced by the language specification. ***However*** the Visual C++ compiler have an extension that allows rvalues to be passed to such a function.

Comment: I believe that would produce a compiler warning, but not error? Granted, there is a compiler-specific way to elevate a specific warning to error, and this warning is a very solid candidate for that in any project, but I'd much prefer a portable, language-enforced way.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe If you are using the Visual Studio 2017 compiler, pass `/permissive-` to it. In prior versions, I believe there is a flag for disabling compiler extensions

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Old MSVC flag is `/Za` I believe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Justin: thanks, I didn't know about `/permissive-`, that is an awesome feature!

Answer (score 1):

An addition to other answers, I'd like to note that there is an example in the Standard library that corresponds exactly to what OP wants - `std::addressof`:

```
template<class T>
constexpr T* addressof(T&) noexcept;

template<class T>
const T* addressof(const T&&) = delete;
```

Comment: Thanks, an interesting analogy. But as soon as I want to cast references (which I do), it will no longer work.