# How can I prevent a const reference to bind to an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, rvalue-reference, enable-if

I just spent too much time debugging something that I think could have been caught at compiletime, but no matter what I tried, I didn't get it to work.

The wrong code:

```
#include <string>
template<typename ContainerT>
std::pair<typename ContainerT::const_iterator, 
          typename ContainerT::const_iterator>
GetIterPair(const ContainerT& container) {
    return { container.cbegin(), container.cend() };
}

int main() {
    GetIterPair(std::string("hello"));
}
```

I tried lots of `enable_if` variants with `!is_rvalue_reference<ContainerT>` and `is_lvalue_reference<...>`, as a template argument and as a trailing return type, but couldn't get it to reject the rvalue.

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995657/overload-a-method-in-a-way-that-generates-a-compiler-error-when-called-with-a-te

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fl5cCYvcoWjlqr9p